# How to hide folder in url bar

Tags: .htaccess

I need to hide folder name in my url bar.

Now I have `mateotxt.pl/website/regulamin.html`

But I need

`mateotxt.pl/regulamin.html`

I need to skip this folder name in my url bar.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: Anything of relevance? https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/105820/transparent-redirection-from-domain-to-subdomain

Answer (score 1):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?regulamin\.html$ /website/regulamin.html [END]
```

In case you are looking for a general rule that might be of help:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/website/
RewriteRule /website%{REQUEST_URI} [END]
```

Though you need to take care that you do not actually rewrite resources you do *not* want to get rewritten that way. So maybe resources stored in *other* folders in the server side file system...

You should implement those directives in the actual http server's host configuration. If you do not have access to that you can use a distributed configuration file (often named ".htaccess"), but that comes with a performance penalty...

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^website/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ website/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: @MateoWarszawa And? What "more information" did you actually see in that error log file?

Comment: The issue here is that the `RewriteCond` will always match, since `%{REQUEST_URI}` contains the _absolute_ path of the requested URI, so a path starting with `/`. Which is why this will result in an endless rewriting loop ...

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/string/
RewriteRule ^string/(.*)$ https://www.domain.eu/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Also this does not rewrite the incoming request to the new, desired URL, but only redirects requests to the old URL.

Comment: Your question, dear friend, conveys this concept.
If this is not used by you, please explain the question further.

Comment: @MohammadrezaGolshahi arkascha is not the one asking the question.